# How to use a local object before it is declared?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, local, instantiation, gameobject

I am making an if statement and I am trying to check if a game object exists, If it does exist I want to destroy it and then recreate it.
If it does not exist I want to create it.

I get the error cannot use local variable before it is not declared.
I have tried declaring it before but then it says cannot use enclosing local scope.

How can I use variable before it is declared or scoped?

Here is my code.

```cs
if (x > 25)
        {
            if (newGameObject.scene.IsValid())
            {
                Destroy(newGameObject);
                GameObject newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
            else
            {
                GameObject newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a new variable called "newGameObject" if one already exists.

So what TerribleDog is suggesting is you declare the property at the class level.

```
class YourClass: MonoBehaviour 
{
    GameObject newGameObject
    void SomeMethod 
    {
        Destroy(newGameObject);
        //Then here just set the class level property
        newGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(object1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it to `GameObject newGameObject = null;` https://www.google.com/search?q=use+of+unssigned+variable

Comment: Change `newGameObject.scene.IsValid()` to `newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid()` as well.

Comment: I have tried newGameObject != null && newGameObject.scene.IsValid()
That worked , but it does not destroy the objects, they remain on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Declare it globally first.

```
GameObject obj;
```

Then on a method you can initialize it.

```
public void try()
{
    obj = new GameObject();
}
```